# How do I write a Dataset from generator to replace Dataset from slices in tensorflow for a tabular data set with X_train and y_train

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

The following works but consumes all my GPU memory as the dataset gets larger.

```
tf_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).shuffle(1000).batch(512, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(1)
```

I tried various options but am stuck on how to write the generator.

```
tf_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=my_gen, output_signature=??)
```

I don't know how to write my_gen nor the output signature syntax.

X_train is a dataframe of numerical features and y_train is a df containing a numerical target variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your generator function to :

```
def generate_sample():
    x = list("123456789")
    y = list("2345")
    while 1:
        yield np.array(x).astype(np.float32), (
            np.array(y).astype(np.float32),
            np.array(y).astype(np.float32),
        )
```

output signature,

```
def generate_sample():
    x = list("123456789")
    y = list("2345")
    while 1:
        yield np.array(x).astype(np.float32), (
            np.array(y).astype(np.float32),
            np.array(y).astype(np.float32),
        )
```